# how to get this elements using template toolkit

Tags: perl, templates, template-toolkit

Hi I have xml data like this

```
<university>
     <name>svu</name>
     <location>ravru</location>
      <branch>
           <electronics>
                  <Section>
                      <student name="xxx" number="12">
                           <sem semister="1"subjects="7" rank="1"/>
                           <sem semister="2"subjects="4" rank="1"/>
                      <student>
                      <student name="xxx" number="15">
                           <sem semister="1"subjects="7" rank="10"/>
                           <sem semister="2"subjects="4" rank="1"/>
                      <student>
                      <student name="xxx" number="16">
                           <sem semister="1"subjects="7" rank="2"/>
                           <sem semister="2"subjects="4" rank="2"/>
                      <student>
                 </section>
            </electronics>
         </branch>
 </university>
 <university>
     <name>sku</name>
     <location>ANTP</location>
      <branch>
           <computers>
                  <Section>
                      <student name="xxx" number="12">
                           <sem semister="1"subjects="7" rank="no"/>
                           <sem semister="2"subjects="4" rank="no"/>
                      <student>
                      <student name="xxx" number="15">
                           <sem semister="1"subjects="7" rank="10"/>
                           <sem semister="2"subjects="4" rank="1"/>
                      <student>
                      <student name="xxx" number="16">
                           <sem semister="1"subjects="7" rank="20"/>
                           <sem semister="2"subjects="4" rank="21"/>
                      <student>
                 </section>
            </electronics>
         </branch>
 </university>
```

I used XML::Simple and I generated hash structured data and stored in a variable. I used template::toolkit to generate pdffile(using pdflatex).my XML::simple output is like this

```
$var1={
     university=>{
          'name'=>'svu',
           'location'=>'ravru',
            'branch'=>{
                     'electronics'=>{
                                'section'=>[
                                         {
                                        'name'=>'xxx',
                                         'number'=>'12',
                                           'sem'=>[
                                                {
                                               'semister'=>'1',
                                                'subjects'=>'7',
                                                 'rank'=>'1'
                                                  },
                                                 {
                                                'semister'=>'2',
                                                'subjects'=>'4',
                                                 'rank'=>'1'
                                                  }
                                                 ]
                                               },
                                             {
                                        'name'=>'xxx',
                                         'number'=>'15',
                                           'sem'=>[
                                                {
                                               'semister'=>'1',
                                                'subjects'=>'7',
                                                 'rank'=>'10'
                                                  },
                                                 {
                                                'semister'=>'1',
                                                'subjects'=>'7',
                                                 'rank'=>'1'
                                                  }
                                                 ]
                                               },
                                              {
                                        'name'=>'xxx',
                                         'number'=>'16',
                                           'sem'=>[
                                                {
                                               'semister'=>'1',
                                                'subjects'=>'7',
                                                 'rank'=>'2'
                                                  },
                                                 {
                                                'semister'=>'2',
                                                'subjects'=>'4',
                                                 'rank'=>'2'
                                                  }
                                                 ]
                                               }
                                             }
                                          ]
                                         }
                                       };
```

like this I have 15 universities and also some section having only two or three students some having 10 students, in students some body only one sem some having two semesters like that.I written template like this

```
my $template = Template->new();
 my $filename = 'output.tex';
   $template->process(\*DATA, $data, $filename)
|| die "Template process failed: ", $template->error(), "\n";
  system( "pdflatex $filename" );
  __DATA__
 \documentclass[a4paper,leqno,twoside]{article}
  \begin{document}
  [% FOREACH st = university %]
   [%+ st.name +%]
   [%+ st.location +%]
 [% FOREACH section = st.branch.electronics.section %]
  branch student: [%+ section.name +%]
 [%+ section.number +%]
 [% FOREACH sem = section.sem %]
    [%+ sem.semister +%]
    [%+ sem.subjects +%]
    [%+ sem.rank +%]
[% END %]
 [% END %]
   [% END %]
  /end{document}
```

like this it giving output but My problem is its too lengthy and also I said above some section have two students and some sections have more than two. for example first section contains 1 student and second section contains 10 students like that. but in pdf first section also printing 10 students only first student have information remaining all empty. how can I eliminate this problem.
If you dont understand my problem just how can I get the data using shorter code than i written. is there any other way to get branch elements all with simpler using for loop for branch elements or any simple code.because if some section have 60 students so it printing 6o in every section.

Comment: please can you tell me how can I use loop inside for loop for only getting section information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just need another `FOREACH` on the sections, something like this:

```
[%+ university.name +%]
[%+ university.location +%]
[% FOREACH section = university.branch.electronics.section %]
    branch student: [%+ section.name +%]
    [%+ section.number +%]
    [% FOREACH sem = section.sem %]
        [%+ sem.semister +%]
        [%+ sem.subjects +%]
        [%+ sem.rank +%]
    [% END %]
[% END %]
```

You might want to add a [custom filter](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Filters.html), [custom vmethod](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/VMethods.html), or [plugin](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Plugins.html) to make sure all your strings are properly escaped for use in LaTeX. If you don't care about how newlines are treated then use `[% ... %]`, the `[%+ ... +%]` version preserves leading and trailing whitespace.

Comment: Hi, I tried like as you said but it giving output only if we have two or more students in a section and also it prints only one semister subjects and rank in one student. if we have two semisters in one student it does't print second sem.

Comment: @pavani: I think I misunderstood the structure of your data, have a look at my update please.

Comment: @pavani: Your best bet is to standardize the data so that `section`, `sem`, `university`, and anything else that can repeat is always represented as an array rather than an array when there are several but a single hash-ref when there's only one. The XML loader you're using should have an option for that.

Comment: @pavani: XML::Simple is fine, have a look at the [`ForceArray`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm#ForceArray_=>_1_#_in_-_important) option, you can also use [`ForceArray` on just a few elements](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Simple/lib/XML/Simple.pm#ForceArray_=>_[_names_]_#_in_-_important). So use `ForceArray` on the things in the XML that will sometimes contain multiple items and then you can always treat those as arrays in your Perl and TT.

Comment: Hi I used ForceArray for repeated elements now its working and printing what I want. Thank you very much for your suggestion and helping.

Comment: ,Hi sorry for asking once again my question is in my student element I have number and name, and also i have same data student name and number with address. I need to search each student name and number in that data if match found then get the address and print along with student name and number. can you suggest me what should i do.

Comment: @pavani: Another question might be a good idea, that would give you more room to describe what you're doing.

Comment: ,can you have a look at my new post please.

Answer (score 1):

What you have pasted above does not seems syntactically correct. Are you jocking :) ?

Anyway, read the [Introduction of the manual](http://template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Intro.html)....
After passing your structure to the TT stash you can acces its elements for example like:

`[% var1.STC.0.gym.hyd.com (AND SO ON) %]`

You should avoid too deep structures.

Comment: sorry its not jocking now you can look at my hole problem explained above. still if you dnt understand ask me.